# should I use scratch area for storing data in Ubuntu?

Tags: ext4

In my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation most partitions are formatted as nfs, including the home directory (and I don't have admin rights to change it). Recently some apps (dropbox) require me to put data on an ext4 partition. In my machine, there are only two places formatted as ext4:

```
/tmp
/scratch
```

The /tmp area space is not sufficient. So my only option is to store data in /scratch. My question is: what is the purpose of /scratch and is it safe to store data on it?

Comment: You should check with the person who administers your computers. `/scratch` isn't present on systems normally.

Comment: @DKBose in my machine it is always there, and has a folder called "lost+found" under it. Asking the administrator is the last resort since he is unlikely to reformat the (shared) nfs partitions.